# GCC/G++ compiles code to shared library instead of executable

Tags: gcc, g++, clang

I am having a rather puzzling problem. Recently, whenever I compile a program using GCC or G++, the compiler creates a shared library rather than an executable file. The library still runs if I execute it via CLI, but the system still treats it as a shared library in all other aspects. I have tested this problem with multiple files, and have found that while it always happens with GCC or G++, it never happens with clang. Help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You say "the system still treats it as a shared library in all other aspects". What specifically do you notice it doing?

Comment: Is this on Linux? What does `file` say on your object files? Can we see the command line that your compiler is used with?

Comment: @JosephSible Namely, when I click on the file, it says "Could not display <program name>. There is no application installed for "shared library" files."

Comment: @dhag `file` outputs the following: `test.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped`. I compiled it with `g++ -c test.cpp && g++ test.o -o test`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I'm running Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: Can you confirm that the file has the execute bit set? If so, it seems like a bug in Nautilus (or whatever file manager you're using to try to open it), and not an issue with the compiler.

Comment: @JosephSible It does have the execute bit set. How do I go about remedying the problem with Nautilus?

Comment: @JosephSible Actually, the problem is not with Nautilus. I installed Konqueror and I still have the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you have an `int main` function?

Comment: @Cosine Yes, I'm sure.

Comment: `test.o` really ought to be relocatable, so all is well there. Your actual executable is `test`. Is there a problem with `test`?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yes. It's treated as a shared library, not an executable.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 16.10 and tested it. Its gcc is built with the `--enable-default-pie` flag, so it will build **p**osition-**I**ndependent **e**xecutables. This is typically done to improve security - the executable's code segment can be loaded at a random address each time the program is exec'ed. The file command reports these executables as shared objects.